# How do you associate a css/sass stylesheet to a view in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, stylesheet

This is a really generic question, to which I haven't found a simple answer.

I'm dealing with messy legacy code that specifies style several times for the same classes/views. I have .sass files in `app/styles`, .css files in `public/stylesheets` and `public/css`

I don't understand which stylesheets includes which, or if they ever do.
How do you match stylesheets to a specific view in rails? How do you define hierarchy between style so ones can override others?

What's the rails default for matching styles to views? I don't see any `stylesheet_link_tag` used in the app

Comment: there has to be some place in your application that is telling it how to load the stylesheets. rails does not automatically include stylesheets in a template without stylesheet_link_tag. it's possible the stylesheets are included manually in the head of your application layout.

Comment: OK thanks! I though Rails would have a default procedure for this

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The best way would be to put a named yield in your application layout:

```
<%= yield :head %>
```

Then use a content for block in your view:

```
<% content_for :head do %>
   <%= stylesheet_link_tag :my_css -%>
<% end %>
```