# Adding a specific stylesheet to a single Rails page

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

I've got a Rails app that has a couple of 'static' pages and I plan to have more in the future.

Current file structure:

```
....
/assets/stylesheets/static.scss
....
/controllers/static_controller.rb
....
/views/static/home.html.erb
/views/static/feedback.html.erb
....
```

My Gemfile contains the 'bootstrap-sass' gem.

I want the `home.html.erb` view to have a different style from all the other 'static' pages, and specifically the following css:

```
html {
    height: 100%;
    background: url(assets/image.jpg) no-repeat center center;
    background-size: cover;
    font-family: Arial;
}

h1 {
    color: black;
    font-style: bold;
    text-align: center;
}
```

How can/should this be achieved most efficiently?  Would I need to create another controller/view/stylesheet for the `home.html.erb`?

CODE:

*application.html.erb:*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Batuk</title>
<%= Gon::Base.render_data({}) %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <%= link_to 'BATUK', root_path, class: "navbar-brand" %>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><%= link_to 'Summary', summary_path %></li>
        <li><%= link_to 'Statement', statement_path %></li>
        <li><%= link_to 'Balances', balances_path %></li>
        <li><%= link_to 'Accounts', accounts_path %></li>
      </ul>

      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><%= link_to 'Feedback', feedback_path %></li>
        <li><%= link_to 'Sign Out', root_path %></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </div>
</nav>

<div class="container">
  <%= yield %>
</div>

<%= render 'layouts/footer' %>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think this answer, from this SO question might help you, http://stackoverflow.com/a/7676570/708807

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to target your controller and action using CSS classes.

In your app/views/layouts/application.html.erb, add `controller_name` and `action_name` method calls to generate the CSS classes.

```
<body class="<%= controller_name %> <%= action_name %>">
```

CSS

```
html { height: 100% }

body.home {
    height: 100%;
    background: url('assets/image.jpg') no-repeat center center;
    background-size: cover;
    font-family: Arial;
}

.home h1 {
    color: black;
    font-style: bold;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a layout with matching name,for your static_controller, template name should be static.html.erb.
then specify the layout in your controller

```
 class staticController < ApplicationController
  layout 'static'
 end
```