# Rails 6: Separate styles and layout for dashboard and main (front) site

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I will try to explain my issue as much as I can.

I hope you guys can understand and give me an idea / help me.

So I am working on a practice app. There are two separate bootstrap html/css design for both of my dashboard and main site.

[image]

Here's the dashboard design:
[image]

Here's the main site design:
[image]

Both of these used bootstrap but separate set of custom design css as well js files.

So far I created a CRUD feature for both of my pages and posts (controller, migration, model, views)

[image]

Now I am confused on whether I'll create another controller for the dashboard and create a different folder on the views for that and how I can actually link the dashboard to my created pages, controller views so far as well as controller.  Wondering also if I can create separate layout file for my dashboard and main site.

I hope it make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should I'll create another controller for the dashboard and create a different folder on the views for that?
>
> Wondering also if I can create separate layout file for my dashboard and main site.

Yes, because they are literally two separate layouts.

There is no hard rule for controller separation, but in this case it's a nice way to separate one group of business logic (site front) from another (dashboard). So I would make a `DashboardController` and put layout for it in `app/views/layouts/dashboard.html.erb`

[This is how Rails decided which layout to use](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#finding-layouts)

> how I can actually link the dashboard to my created pages, controller views so far as well as controller

Using [UrlHelper](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.3/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to), like usually.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to solve this problem.

But I think you are on the right way by creating seperate controller and views. A controller for the main site and one for the dashboard.

This has the great effect that you can handle the request more specific for both sides.
I think you want to add authorization for the dashboard. So you would implement this in the dashboard_controller.rb.

For specific css for a rails page: [Adding a specific stylesheet to a single Rails page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35806366/adding-a-specific-stylesheet-to-a-single-rails-page)

I hope this was helpfully.